# Getting mixed results. Some content is compressed, others not

Tags: azure-cdn

Using Standard Verizon CDN. Origin is Blob Storage. Accept-Type is always set, but only certain JS content returned is compressed with gzip. I've tried going through the CDN compression troubleshooting doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-troubleshoot-compression) but it doesn't help. What's next in troubleshooting?

Comment: Can you share an example url of both a compressed and un-compressed file?

Comment: Here's one that's not gzipped, while the one after is: https://az######.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/app/routes/dashboard.js?v=1064445226

https://az######.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/deploy/dg1.js?v=1064445226

When an blob is updated at the origin, could that cause the CDN to stop compressing things for a while? If so, how long? How does that work? We currently don't compress the content before we upload it to the CDN, would doing so resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/cdn

> In Azure the default mechanism is to automatically compress content when CPU utilization is below 50%.

This may/may not be your problem. There's a setting on portal.azure to enable compression on the fly, which I think would be the solution